# How to get hover effect to reset when cursor is outside canvas area?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to set up a hover effect where the image will follow the cursor inside the canvas, but when the mouse goes outside of the canvas area I would like the image to move back to its center position.

My canvas and image are fine:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="550px" height="550px" style="border: 2px solid red" class="paddingleft">
```

But I need to fix something in with the javascript/jquery so that it will do what I like:

```
var AN = AN || {};

var pic = new Image();
var canvas;
var context;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

AN.initialize = function() {
  //load canvas
  canvas = $('#canvas');
  canvas.mousemove(AN.moveMouse);
  context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  //load image
  pic.src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0539/9904/2739/files/smiley.png?v=1614313440";
};
pic.height = 400;
pic.width = 400;

AN.moveMouse = function (e) {
  var element = $(pic);
  var t = 0; //0-1, this is what you change in animation loop
  var position = getMousePosition(e);
  function myLoop() {  
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());

    x += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.x - x);
    y += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.y - y);

    // set element by tx
    context.drawImage(pic, x, y, pic.width, pic.height);

    if (t < 1) {
      t += 0.01; //determines speed
      requestAnimationFrame(myLoop);
      //setTimeout(myLoop, 16); //option to above
    }
  }
  myLoop();
};

EasingFunctions = {
  linear: function(t) {
    return t;
  },
  easeInQuad: function(t) {
    return t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t * (2 - t);
  },
  easeInOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;
  },
  easeInCubic: function(t) {
    return t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutCubic: function(t) {
    return (--t) * t * t + 1;
  },
  easeInOutCubic: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1;
  },
  easeInQuart: function(t) {
    return t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuart: function(t) {
    return 1 - (--t) * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInOutQuart: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 8 * t * t * t * t : 1 - 8 * (--t) * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInQuint: function(t) {
    return t * t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuint: function(t) {
    return 1 + (--t) * t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInOutQuint: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 16 * t * t * t * t * t : 1 + 16 * (--t) * t * t * t * t;
  }
}

function getMousePosition(e) {
    return {
        x: e.clientX - pic.width * 0.5,
        y: e.clientY - pic.height * 0.5
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //initialize funtion
  AN.initialize();
});

</canvas>
```

I'm not sure if anyone will be able to help me but if someone can I would appreciate it.

Here is my code pen for convience:

https://codepen.io/kyannashanice/pen/gOLymYe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. As solution I just added a mouseOut function and recalculated the smiley position. You can optimize the code further

```js
var AN = AN || {};
var pic = new Image();
var canvas;
var context;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;


AN.initialize = function() {
  //load canvas
  canvas = $('#canvas');
  canvas.mousemove(AN.moveMouse);
  canvas.mouseout(AN.mouseOut);
  context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
  //load image
  pic.src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0539/9904/2739/files/smiley.png?v=1614313440";
};
pic.height = 400;
pic.width = 400;

function calculatePosition(position) {
  var element = $(pic);
   var t = 0; //0-1, this is what you change in animation loop
  function myLoop() {  
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());

    x += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.x - x);
    y += EasingFunctions.easeInOutQuad(t) * (position.y - y);

    // set element by tx
    context.drawImage(pic, x, y, pic.width, pic.height);

    if (t < 1) {
      t += 0.01; //determines speed
      requestAnimationFrame(myLoop);
      //setTimeout(myLoop, 16); //option to above
    }
  }
  myLoop();
}

AN.mouseOut = function () {
   calculatePosition({x:80, y:80});
}

AN.moveMouse = function (e) {
  var position = getMousePosition(e);
  calculatePosition(position);
};

EasingFunctions = {
  linear: function(t) {
    return t;
  },
  easeInQuad: function(t) {
    return t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t * (2 - t);
  },
  easeInOutQuad: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;
  },
  easeInCubic: function(t) {
    return t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutCubic: function(t) {
    return (--t) * t * t + 1;
  },
  easeInOutCubic: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1;
  },
  easeInQuart: function(t) {
    return t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuart: function(t) {
    return 1 - (--t) * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInOutQuart: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 8 * t * t * t * t : 1 - 8 * (--t) * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInQuint: function(t) {
    return t * t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeOutQuint: function(t) {
    return 1 + (--t) * t * t * t * t;
  },
  easeInOutQuint: function(t) {
    return t < .5 ? 16 * t * t * t * t * t : 1 + 16 * (--t) * t * t * t * t;
  }
}

function getMousePosition(e) {
    return {
        x: e.clientX - pic.width * 0.5,
        y: e.clientY - pic.height * 0.5
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //initialize funtion
  AN.initialize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="550px" height="550px" style="border: 2px solid red" class="paddingleft">

</canvas>
```

Comment: @KyannaShanice I have hardcoded the value of x and y as 80 as of now. you might need to recalculate(to bring it to the exact center) according to your requirement. Please do accept the answer if this helps

Comment: sorry about that - I have accepted the answer. Thank you for the heads up, I have another question, how would I make it so that the image is visible outside of the canvas? Like when it goes over the edge I would like to be able to see that. I'm trying to create an effect similar to the images that follow your cursor on this site (https://www.readthissummer.com/)

Comment: @KyannaShanice I will check that out and let you know soon. Meanwhile, as we have an accepted answer, I'm not sure if you will get sufficient reach for your second question in case I couldn't do it. You can create it as a new question.

Comment: unfortunately i'm unable to ask questions for the next 4 days so I will have to try and post elsewhere, thank you for the advice though!

Comment: @KyannaShanice. I'm not that great at HTML canvas. But I was wondering why u need to move the image out of the canvas. I have referenced few articles and created a pen on this. https://codepen.io/vinu_pen/pen/wvoZOvg Hope this is what you are looking for.
Credit: https://www.digimantra.com/tutorials/drag-an-element-image-etc-using-javascript-html-css/

Comment: thank you for coming back and helping me! I figured it out actually with some help from reddit. I will link the completed codepen later today!